# arithmetic operator in SQL HAVING clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, database, having, dml

Can I have arithmetic operator in SQL having clause? Because from what i know arithmetic operators are only allowed in SELECT and WHERE clause. But the following code make sense to me though, but I know it serves no purpose. Any advice?

```
 SELECT E.name
 FROM Example E
 GROUP BY E.name
 HAVING COUNT(*) + 2 > 4
```

Comment: why don't you just try it and see what you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "arithmetic operator" in a HAVING clause.

The expression in the HAVING clause will be evaluated as a boolean.

---

NOTE: be sure the order of precedence is what you expect, e.g.

```
( COUNT(*) + 2 ) > 4
```

vs

```
COUNT(*) + ( 2 > 4 )
```

In your example, the addition isn't really required; the expression could be replace with the logically equivalent:

```
COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: Just a side note: your second example would fail in almost every other DBMS as MySQL doesn't really distinguish between boolean values and numbers. Anything not equal to 0 is considered "true"

Comment: good points. Any non-null not equal to zero is considered "true".

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more complicated arithmetic expression, you can use a subquery:

```
select
    *
from
(
    select
        cnt = COUNT(*) + 2
        , E.Name
    from
        Example E
    group by
        E.name
) as subQ
where
    subQ.cnt > 4
```

Comment: "If you want a more complicated ..." hahaha

Comment: Should `cnt = ...` be `... as cnt`?